# Python how to avoid "side effect"

Tags: python, side-effects

I heard that below code is side-effective python code,
because counts list changes ***def count_case()*** and does not work as I expected. **Side effects** are the changes that a function makes to its implicit context.

```
def main():
    word_list = ['hELLo', '', 'C7pX4%']
    counts = [0, 0]
    for word in word_list:
        count_case(word, counts)
        print('Word:', word)
        print('Lowercase count: ', counts[0])
        print('Uppercase count: ', counts[1])

def count_case(string, counts):
    for letter in string:
        if letter.islower():
            counts[0] = counts[0] + 1
        if letter.isupper():
            counts[1] = counts[1] + 1
main()
```

So, I changed code as below.

```
def main():
    word_list = ['hELLo', '', 'C7pX4%']
    for word in word_list:
        counts = count_case(word, counts=[0, 0])
        print('Word:', word)
        print('Lowercase count: ', counts[0])
        print('Uppercase count: ', counts[1])

def count_case(string, counts):
    for letter in string:
        if letter.islower():
            counts[0] = counts[0] + 1
        if letter.isupper():
            counts[1] = counts[1] + 1
    return counts
main()
```

Then, it works well, but I still wonder 1) whether it has side effects or not. I want to know 2) how to avoid side effect.

Comment: 1. Yes, it still has a side effect. 2. Maybe count_case should create its own list to return? Then the caller is responsible for aggregating the results from each call.

Comment: By any chance are you coming to Python from a C background (where it is common to pass to a function a pointer to an array intended to gather the results)? Passing a list of `0` to a function just to have that function replace those zeros with actual data seems odd. What is the motivation for that? Why pass `counts` at all? For this special case, I would drop a list completely and just have the function return a pair of counts: `return lower, upper`.

Comment: In so many words, a pure function *only* returns a result; it does not modify its input parameters or anything else in its environment. The obvious and immediate benefit is that you can see what code does without having to examine each function it calls to check whether it does something more than what's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way by using object destructuring and an inner function:

```
def main():
    word_list = ['hELLo', '', 'C7pX4%']
    for word in word_list:
        lowers, uppers = count_case(word)
        print('Word:', word)
        print('Lowercase count: ', lowers)
        print('Uppercase count: ', uppers)

    def count_case(string):
        lowers = 0
        uppers = 0
        for letter in string:
           if letter.islower():
               lowers = lowers + 1
           if letter.isupper():
               uppers = uppers + 1
        return lowers, uppers
main()
```